# Interpolation with barriers in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, interpolation, kriging, barriers

Does anyone have a code example or helpful information to conduct Empirical Bayesian kriging on Google Earth Engine or of an interpolation with barriers technique in Google Earth Engine?